# Scatter plot does not appear on the foreground on top of contourf plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, subplot, contourf

My code is the following and I believe should produce a chart where a `scatter` plot is superimposed on a `contourf` plot (i.e. appears on the foreground)

But that does not happen.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(examples[:,0], examples[:, 1])
ax.contourf(x, y, Z)
```

[image]

I expected that the `scatter` plot below would be superimposed on the `contourf` plot:

```
plt.scatter(x = examples[:,0], y = examples[:, 1])
```

[image]

Why is this and how the code should be changed?

Comment: First do the `contourf`, then `scatter`?

Comment: If you really need to call `scatter` earlier than `contourf`, use `ax.scatter(..., zorder=2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap `contourf` and `scatter` order:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000
xl = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
yl = np.linspace(0, 10, N)
x, y = np.meshgrid(xl, yl)
Z = x**2 + y**2

examples = np.random.uniform(low = 0, high = 10, size = (10, 2))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.contourf(x, y, Z)
ax.scatter(examples[:,0], examples[:, 1], color = 'red')

plt.show()
```

[image]

The last plot line you write overlaps the previous one.